# How to use attrs validators in a post-init hook?

Tags: python, attr

I would like to transform a class which uses attrs validators to instead collect all the errors and put them in a list which will be an attribute of that class:

```
def positive_finite(full_instance, attribute_type, value):
    if not isfinite(value):
        raise ValueError(f"{attribute_type.name} is not finite")
    if value < 0.0:
        raise ValueError(f"{attribute_type.name} is negative")
@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=True)
class Test:
    C: float = attr.ib(validator=positive_finite)
    Mn: float = attr.ib(validator=positive_finite)
```

So something like this would not allow me to create an instance of this class with not finite or negative numbers. For example `test = Test(C=2.0, Mn=-2.1)` would result in a `ValueError "Mn is negative"`

```
def positive_finite(attribute_type, value):
    if not isfinite(value):
        return f"{attribute_type} is not finite"
    if value < 0.0:
        return f"{attribute_type} is negative"

@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=True)
class Test:
    C: float = attr.ib()
    Mn: float = attr.ib()
    List_of_errors: list = attr.ib(init=False)
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "List_of_errors", [x for x in [positive_finite(type(self).C.__name__, self.C), positive_finite(type(self).Mn.__name__, self.Mn)] if x is not None])
```

So using a post-init hook I am creating a `List_of_errors` which checks all of my criteria and if some of them are broken, it still allows me to create an instance of this class and saves the error messages to a `List_of_errors`. So `test = Test(C=2.0, Mn=-2.1)` would still create an instance of this class `Test(C=2.0, Mn=-2.1, List_of_errors=['Mn is negative'])`

This is indeed what I want, however is there any way to incorporate validators directly in this? `positive_finite(type(self).C.__name__, self.C)` is not very readable for someone else, it also requires a lot of the same code in my post-init hook and also is very slow (in my actual scenario I have 40 attributes that need different validations).

Comment: What Python version do you use ? Because attr is not working the way you use it with Python 3.

Comment: I am using python 3.8, which part does not work for you? @areop-enap